# Elemento com onClick e onDblClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho uma lista e nessa lista estou a tentar distinguir um **click** de um **double click**

Usei inicialmente no **HTML**:

```
<a class = "alinhar1" href="#" ondblclick="list.oneDblClick();"  onClick="list.oneClick();">
```

Mas sempre que faço um **double click**, o **click** também é chamado.

Já experimentei usar uma flag para tentar bloquear o acesso ao **click**, mas sem sucesso.

Já pensei também em só usar o `onClick` e depois dentro do método verificar se houve outro click seguinte, mas também sem sucesso

Existe alguma solução ou alguma alternativa para me ajudar a ultrapassar esta dicifuldade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar o `type` do evento para os destinguir, e chamas uma função intermédia que faz routing para a que queres.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
<a class = "alinhar1" href="#" ondblclick="clickHandler(event)"  onClick="clickHandler(event)">'
```

e depois a função:

```
function clickHandler(e){
    if (e.type == 'dblclick') list.oneDblClick(e);
    else if (e.type == 'click') list.oneClick(e);
}
```

Não estou bem certo de que browsers suportam o `dblclick` mas os modernos suportam todos julgo eu.

### Edit:

Reparei agora que ambos os eventos são disparados no Chrome. Aqui fica uma solução para isso que espera meio segundo para ter certeza de que evento se trata:

```
var list = {
    oneClick: function (e) {
        alert('um clique do tipo: ' + e.type);
    },
    oneDblClick: function (e) {
        alert('dois clique do tipo: ' + e.type);
    },
    timeout: null
};

function clickHandler(e) {
    (function () {
        var type = e.type;
        var evt = e;
        var verificador = function () {
            list.timeout = null;
            if (type == 'dblclick') list.oneDblClick(evt);
            else if (type == 'click') list.oneClick(evt);
        }
        if (list.timeout) clearTimeout(list.timeout)
        list.timeout = setTimeout(verificador, 500);
    })();
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9rLb8wsy/

Comment: não é preciso por esse parametro `event` também no `onclick`?

Comment: @msm.oliveira é sim, obrigado. Corrigí.

Comment: @msm.oliveira bom que a resposta ajudou. Eu vou ainda atualizar daqui a pouco com uma ideia, depois comento também.

Comment: @msm.oliveira adicionei mais info na resposta.